# Send Ctrl + C to asyncio Task

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

So I have two tasks running until complete in my event loop. I want to handle KeyboardInterrupt when running those Tasks and send the same signal to the Tasks in the event loop when receiving it.

```
 loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
            task_1(),
            task_2()
        ))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
        # Here I want to send sigterm to the tasks in event loop
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`asyncio.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) instead. `asyncio.run()` cancels all tasks/futures when receiving exceptions.

[`asyncio.gather()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) would then cancel the tanks when itself is cancelled. You may capture `asyncio.CancelledError` around `asyncio.sleep()` to see.  Discard it would keep the task running.

```py
async def task_1():
    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
    except asyncio.CancelledError as ex:
        print('task1', type(ex))
        raise


async def task_2():
    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
    except asyncio.CancelledError as ex:
        print('task2', type(ex))
        raise


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(task_1(), task_2())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Otherwise, you need to keep references to tasks, cancel them, and re-run the event loop to propagate `CancelledError`, like what `asynio.run()` do under the hood.